# Linq select distinct count performed in memory

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm working on understanding how LINQ converts to SQL.

I have the following query I'm trying to generate using LINQ.

```
SELECT [OrganizationId]
  ,[DepartmentId]
  ,[LocationName]
  ,[Group1]
  ,[Group2]
  ,[Group3]
  ,[BooklistId]
  ,[BooklistName]
  ,COUNT(DISTINCT [OrdererId])
  ,MAX([ExpectedDate])
FROM [Orders]
WHERE ([DepartmentId] IS NOT NULL AND ([DepartmentId] = '<Guid>')) AND ([Schoolyear] = '2018')
GROUP BY [OrganizationId]
  ,[DepartmentId]
  ,[LocationName]
  ,[Group1]
  ,[Group2]
  ,[Group3]
  ,[BooklistId]
  ,[BooklistName]
ORDER BY [BooklistName]
```

With indexes this query performs under 200ms.

My LINQ query is the following:

```
await _context
            .Orders
            .Where(i => i.DepartmentId != null && i.DepartmentId.Equals(Parameters.DepartmentId))
            .Where(i => i.SchoolYear.Equals(Parameters.SchoolYear))
            // Group the data.
            .GroupBy(orders => new
            {
                orders.BooklistId,
                orders.BooklistName,
                orders.OrganizationId,
                orders.DepartmentId,
                orders.LocationName,
                orders.Groep1,
                orders.Groep2,
                orders.Groep3
            })
            .OrderBy(i => i.Key.BooklistName)
            .Select(i => new BookListViewModel
            {
                Count = i.Select(orders => orders.OrdererId).Distinct().Count(s => s != null),
                Id = i.Key.OrganizationId,
                Name = i.Key.BooklistName,
                LocationName = i.Key.LocationName,
                Number = i.Key.BooklistId,
                Group1 = i.Key.Group1,
                Group2 = i.Key.Group2,
                Group3 = i.Key.Group3,
                DepartmentId = i.Key.DepartmentId,
                ExpectedDate = i.Max(orders => orders.ExpectedDate)
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```

However I keep seeing:

> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'GroupBy(new <>f__AnonymousType1`8(BooklistId = [i].BooklistId, BooklistName = [i].BooklistName, OrganizationId = [i].OrganizationId, DepartmentId = [i].DepartmentId, LocationName = [i].LocationName, Group1 = [i].Group1, Group2 = [i].Group2, Group3 = [i].Group3), [i])' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Distinct()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'where ([s] != null)' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.
>
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query:Warning: The LINQ expression 'Count()' could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.

Can anyone tell me why the LINQ query performs in memory? What do I need to change in the LINQ query to get the result I want?

Comment: I don't think `Count()` and `Distinct()` are supported just yet...

Comment: My guess is that the second and third warning follows because of the first warning, and that Distinct() isn't supported by EFC, meaning EFC can't translate the distinct function to sql on a custom select query.

Comment: I can tell you guys Select and Distinct are supported in EFC. I have another query where I select and distinct count the unique orderer ids. However this is written differently.

await _context
                .Orders
                .Select(orders => orders.OrdererId)
                .Distinct()
                .CountAsync();

Generates: SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT [orders].[ordererid]
    FROM [orders]
) AS [t]

Comment: As a first step, why not remove the inner lambda for the count so that at least your two statements are equivalent?

Comment: I propose you turn on your sql profiler to understand what EF is creating as sql's. This gives you good insights on what EF can do for you. I do believe this gies an answer to your question because you want to understand. This allows you to understand what is going on in your particular example

Comment: Select and Distinct might be supported at top level query, but not inside `GroupBy`. The EFC `GroupBy` translation is improved over the time (the last being in [2.1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#linq-groupby-translation)), but sill some constructs are unsupported (even the supported `Min`, `Max`, `Sum` etc. have limitations).

Comment: I'll take this as you said Ivan. It seems this is a limitation of the current .NET Core 2.1.2 framework.

Answer (score 1):

The query is executing in memory because you instantiating a collection of BookListViewModel objects with the statement

```
.Select(i => new BookListViewModel
            {...})
```

If you simply remove the class BookListViewModel, Linq will execute the perform the query on the db side (which is a good idea since the optimizer is much more efficient) like this...

```
.Select(i => new
            {
                Count = i.Select(orders => orders.OrdererId).Distinct().Count(s => s != null),
                i.Key.OrganizationId,
                i.Key.BooklistName,
                i.Key.LocationName,
                i.Key.BooklistId,
                i.Key.Group1,
                i.Key.Group2,
                i.Key.Group3,
                i.Key.DepartmentId,
                ExpectedDate = i.Max(orders => orders.ExpectedDate)
            })
```

Then you can instantiate your collection at the end so the whole thing will look like this...

```
await _context
            .Orders
            .Where(i => i.DepartmentId != null && i.DepartmentId.Equals(Parameters.DepartmentId))
            .Where(i => i.SchoolYear.Equals(Parameters.SchoolYear))
            // Group the data.
            .GroupBy(orders => new
            {
                orders.BooklistId,
                orders.BooklistName,
                orders.OrganizationId,
                orders.DepartmentId,
                orders.LocationName,
                orders.Group1,
                orders.Group2,
                orders.Group3
            })
            .OrderBy(i => i.Key.BooklistName)
.Select(i => new
            {
                Count = i.Select(orders => orders.OrdererId).Distinct().Count(s => s != null),
                i.Key.OrganizationId,
                i.Key.BooklistName,
                i.Key.LocationName,
                i.Key.BooklistId,
                i.Key.Group1,
                i.Key.Group2,
                i.Key.Group3,
                i.Key.DepartmentId,
                ExpectedDate = i.Max(orders => orders.ExpectedDate)
            })
            .Select(i => new BookListViewModel
            {
                Count = i.Count,
                Id = i.Id,
                Name = i.Name,
                LocationName = i.LocationName,
                Number = i.Number ,
                Group1 = i.Group1 ,
                Group2 = i.Group2,
                Group3 = i.Group3,
                DepartmentId = i.DepartmentId,
                ExpectedDate = i.ExpectedDate
            })
            .ToListAsync();
```